# Store and iterate over array of links using Nokogiri/Mechanize

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, nokogiri, mechanize

I'm trying to store a list of links into an array and then iterate through them.

I have this rake task: https://gist.github.com/farooqyousuf/5268460

Currently, the rake task goes through a page and fetches *some* of the links that I need, but it doesn't fetch them *all*.

The problem is line 17.

I need it to do `page2.search('.subtitleLink a').each` but I can't add the `.each` on there with this on the end: `.map{|a| page2.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|`.  It gives an error.

So I'm thinking I need to store `page2.search('.subtitleLink a').each` into an array and then iterate over it executing this code on each iteration (`.map{|a| page2.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|`), but I haven't been successful in my attempts.

**Option 1:**

I tried this:

```
page2.search('.subtitleLink a').each do |x|      
  x.map{|a| page2.uri.merge a[:href]}.each do |uri|
    page4 = agent.get uri
  end
```

But I get this error:

```
rake aborted!
can't convert Symbol into Integer
/Users/farooqyousuf/Projects/HalalSpot/lib/tasks/something.rake:19:in `[]'
```

**Option 2:**

```
                page2.search('.subtitleLink a').each do |x|

                    blah = URI.parse(URI.encode(x.to_s.strip))
                    page4 = agent.get blah

               end
```

Results in:

```
rake aborted!
bad URI(is not URI?): %3Ca%20href=%22http://www.salatomatic.com/d/Hartford+3115+Muhammad-Islamic-Center-%22%3E%3Cb%3EMuhammad%20Islamic%20Center%20%3C/b%3E%3C/a%3E
```

Thoughts?

Comment: What is `page2.uri`? I can't find a definition anywhere in the docs: http://mechanize.rubyforge.org/Mechanize/Page.html

Comment: It returns the uri/url of the page

Comment: That's totally undocumented!

Comment: @joeframbach It is defined in `Mechanize::Parser` which is included by the parent class (`Mechanize::File`) of `Mechanize::Page`

Comment: Oh geez. An entire page of documentation I didn't even know existed

Comment: The code works fine here, at least I can do `map`/`each` on the `a` links. Try to `puts a;` before `page2.uri.merge a[:href]`, it seems `a` has been treated as an Array.

Comment: @ArieShaw After adding 'puts a;' I got this:

href
http://www.salatomatic.com/d/Hartford+3115+Muhammad-Islamic-Center-
rake aborted!
can't convert Symbol into Integer
/Users/farooqyousuf/Projects/HalalSpot/lib/tasks/something.rake:19:in `[]'

Comment: Try replace `a[:href]` with `a.attribute("href").value`, what will you get?

Comment: Got this: rake aborted!
undefined method `attribute' for #<Array:0x007f9b869b33a8>

Comment: I tried another option (Option 2) see post for edits, but I get a bad uri error there...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
puts "Enter the page url from which you wish to import data: "
page = STDIN.gets
page2 = Nokogiri::HTML(open(page))

links = page2.css('.subtitleLink a')

links.each do |link| 
 puts link['href']
 url = link['href'].strip

 page4 = agent.get url

 #do stuff

end
```

Comment: This worked for me...but I don't know why it doesn't scrape all the pages and create records for them for me, just a few pages...